# Linux combine multiple files

Tags: linux, shell, join, awk

I have multiple files has to combine.

This is for example two files.

1.txt

```
Allele Sequence
B*07:02:01 ABCDE
B*07:33:01 ABCD
B*07:41 AB
```

2.txt

```
Allele Sequence
B*07:02:01 FGHIJ     
B*07:33:01 EFGH
B*07:41 CD
```

Delimited is Tab(\t)

I wants to get result like

```
B*07:02:01 ABCDEFGHIJ     
B*07:33:01 ABCDEFGH
B*07:41 ABCD
```

I tried like below.

```
awk -F"\t" '
    {key = $1}
    FNR==NR {line[key]=$0; next}
    key in line {print line[$1], $2}
' $1 $2 > output_2.txt
```

Then result like

```
Allele  Sequence^M Sequence^M
B*07:02:01 ABCDE^M FGHIJ     
B*07:33:01 ABCD^M EFGH
B*07:41 AB^M CD
```

How can I make more clear and exactly what I want

Thanks!

Comment: You might have more luck using a scripting language like Python, Ruby, or Perl.

Comment: Using the `in` `key in line` will randomize the order of the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} FNR>1{print $0 a[$1]} ' 2.txt 1.txt
B*07:02:01 ABCDEFGHIJ
B*07:33:01 ABCDEFGH
B*07:41 ABCD
```

How it works:

```
awk '
FNR==NR {           # For first file only (2.txt)
    a[$1]=$2        # Read data in to array a using $1 as key and $2 as value
    next}           # Skip to next record
FNR>1{              # Skip first record of second file (1.txt)
    print $0 a[$1]} # Print complete record from 1.txt, and data from array using $1 as key
' 2.txt 1.txt       # read the files
```

Comment: almost ! but between ABCD EFGH there is ^M mark, like

Comment: B*07:02:01 ABCD^MEFGH

Comment: @clear.choi With some change, it should be ok know.  You do not need to set `FS` since its default to tab and space.

Comment: @Jotne - Could you also include a brief explanation as to how your `awk` command words?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"\t" '
         {gsub("\r",""); key = $1}
         FNR==NR {line[key]=$0; next}
         key in line {print line[$1]$2}
     ' 1d.txt 2d.txt > x
```

- `gsub` will remove the "^M" you have problems with (it is chr(13)=CR, as your input files are from DOS/windows worlds which use CRLF, and you're processing then on UN*X, which uses only LF as a line separator)
- removing "," in `line[$1]$2` will remove space

Comment: Honestly, I would just post-process the `\r` out using `tr`.  I feel like it would reduce the clutter in the `awk` code.

Comment: @Mr.Llama sure. I was trying to remain as close to possible to your code you understand, and not introduce additional dependencies/tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
join 1.txt 2.txt | awk '{print $1, $2 $3}'
```